# Invoke-Command AsJob parameter set not working

Tags: powershell, batch-file, ansible

I am able to do

`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Z:\prog.bat }`

However, when I do

`Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Z:\prog.bat } -AsJob`

I keep getting

`Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {  z:\prog.bat } - ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand`

My intention is to run Z:\Prog.bat in the background since I will be executing this thru Ansible

Comment: Please confirm your are using `ScriptBlock` and not `ScriptsBlock`. Where are you using this line - in a script, PS console, bat file?

Comment: Yes. Its ScriptBlock. I am doing this line in PowerShell command prompt.

Comment: From the error message, it appears that there is another parameter required for a complete parameter set. See `help Invoke-Command -Full`

Answer (score 3):

Per the comments, this error message is telling you that it's not possible for PowerShell to know which Parameter Set you are trying to use. A Parameter Set is a collection of Parameters that are used together, some mandatory and some optional. Some cmdlets have a single set, some cmdlets have different combinations allowing them to be used in different ways.

You are using `-ScriptBlock` and `-AsJob`. `Invoke-Command` has quite a large number of Parameter Sets and to make your call of these parameters unique you need to use them with one of these parameters:

- `-Session`
- `-ComputerName`
- `-ConnectionUri`
- `-VMId`
- `-VMName`
- `-ContainerID`

E.g:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Z:\prog.bat } -AsJob -Computername SomeComputer
```

Alternatively if you're just attempting to run a script block as a background job on your local machine, don't use `Invoke-Command` instead consider using `Start-Job`:

```
Start-Job { Z:\prog.bat }
```